# What is the difference between

Tags: vocabulary

What is the difference between 
 - respected
 - respectable
 - respectful

my school book tells the difference but i can't understand it from the book because it is embarrassing.

Comment: I'm curious, why is it "embarrassing"?  Do you mean that it would *embarrass* you to ask for help from the teacher?  Or that the example used in the book makes you *embarrassed*?

Comment: It is what in the book

Answer (score 1):

It can be helpful to check English-language dictionaries for the definitions of words:

> **[respected](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/respected)** (adj): Deeply admired or esteemed.
>
> **[respectable](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/respectable)** (adj): 1, Regarded by society to be good, proper, or correct.  1.1 (of a person's appearance, clothes, or behaviour) decent or presentable.
>
> **[respectful](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/respectful)** (adj): Feeling or showing deference and respect.

So someone "respected" is someone who gets *respect* from other people:

> Her father was the only doctor in the small town, and **respected** by everyone.

Someone "respectable" appears to deserve respect, or at least, normally engages in the kind of behavior that other people respect.

> He was a **respectable** old gentleman who everyone greeted as he took his evening walk around the town square.

Someone "respectful" shows respect to other people

> The **respectful** young man took off his hat as he approached the doctor during one of his walks.  "Sir," he began, "I'm a medical student at the university, and I'd like to ask to become your assistant."